# Kotlin - Can the minimum distance between a location and a list of locations be found with a one liner?

Tags: kotlin

I would like the following "pseudocode" to be valid syntax (but clearly it's not) :

```
minDistance = minOf(myLocations.forEach{return location.distanceTo(it)})
```

To clarify, I am trying to find the distance from the smartphone (location) to the closest location in a mutable list of locations (myLocations).

Does Kotlin allow this level of terseness, or must I break it up in a few more lines and help variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for

```
minDistance =  myLocations.minOf { location.distanceTo(it) }
```

Additional info:
If you want the location with the shortest distance instead, then you can use

```
myLocations.minByOrNull { location.distanceTo(it) }
```

Comment: The `minDistance` is just irrelevant, when one possibly would like to know the `location`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler no offense, but can you read OP's mind? The question asked for the distance and even shows a variable called `minDistance` so I'm confident that this is what is desired

Comment: @IvoBeckers The question defeats common sense, when the result might be useless (as the distance alone usually doesn't help much, unless knowing which location it is). The closest location might provide a tad more sense.

Comment: @MartinZeitler i can very well see a use case. Maybe he wants to show a text on the top of a list saying "Here's a list of interesting locations, with the closest only being X meters from you". And I'm sure there are other use cases as well. Nothing useless about it

Comment: This answer is exactly what the OP had asked, but I can also see Martin's point at least in a general use case: it would be nice to have both the shortest distance _and_ the nearest location at the same time. Maybe by using `minOfWith`.

Comment: I'm not really challenging the correct answer, but the question. And even with the stated example, it may help to already know the location, instead of processing twice, in case the user then taps the suggestion ...as the distance to there is merely a detail of it.

Comment: @MartinZeitler i agree with you regarding that, but then I would have made the comment on the question, and not this answer

Comment: @k314159 I guess you could do `myLocations.minOfWith({a,b -> a.distanceTo(location).compareTo(b.distanceTo(location)) }){it}` but I was thinking maybe `myLocations.sortedBy { location.distanceTo(it) }.first()` is better. I'm not sure what's most efficient

Comment: @k314159 I found `myLocations.minByOrNull { location.distanceTo(it) }` also. I think that one is the best since it's specifically made for this